# learn c the hard way chapter heap and stack code

Tags: c, struct, malloc

In Zed's popular (opinion) series, in the chapter 'Heap and stack' the code for a databse is as follows

**Please note this is Zed Shaw's code**

```
struct Address {
    int id;
    int set;
    char name[MAX_DATA];
    char email[MAX_DATA];
};

struct Database {
    struct Address rows[MAX_ROWS];
};

struct Connection {
    FILE *file;
    struct Database *db;
};




struct Connection *Database_open(const char *filename, char mode)
{
    struct Connection *conn = malloc(sizeof(struct Connection));
    if(!conn) die("Memory error");

    conn->db = malloc(sizeof(struct Database));
    if(!conn->db) die("Memory error");

    if(mode == 'c') {
        conn->file = fopen(filename, "w");
    } else {
        conn->file = fopen(filename, "r+");

        if(conn->file) {
            Database_load(conn);
        }
    }

    if(!conn->file) die("Failed to open the file");

    return conn;
}



void Database_create(struct Connection *conn)
{
    int i = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < MAX_ROWS; i++) {
        // make a prototype to initialize it
        struct Address addr = {.id = i, .set = 0};
        // then just assign it
        conn->db->rows[i] = addr;
    }
}
```

I felt in his Database_create function , he calls in  alloted memory of the form struct Address , when memory f was already alloted for the creation of the
struct database , to be strange.

And then I reasoned via that line of thinking the fact that he called malloc twice ,first to allot heap memory for the creation of Connection, and then again for the creation of the struct type within the struct Connection(i.e Databse) should be strange as well..I reasoned that probably Zed knew and understood that struct nests had to be constructed layer by layer.

Just before posting the question here, I decide to write a simple nested struct type and tried accessing the the data within layers of struct via the outmost struct created via one malloc call....my reasoning was that if my thinking that there was no need to construct nested structs layer by layer were true, I could access the nested data without segmentation fault .And I did

The code is as follows

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>




struct Killfly{

    char str[20];

};

struct wtf
{
    struct Killfly a;   
};

struct wtf2{

    struct wtf k;
};


int main(){
    struct wtf2*fly=malloc(sizeof(struct wtf2));
    printf("size of %ld \n",sizeof(*fly));
    fly->k.a.str[0]='a';
    //printf("size of wtf is %ld \n",sizeof(wtf));
    free(fly);

    return 0;

}
```

AND it wrote without a seg fault

**Question**

SO why did Zed place multiple malloc calls , and why when he already allocated space for the struct Database, in the function Database_struct , in a for loop, he goes on  to call stack based struct Address objects and place them in the array of said types?

Comment: "SO why did Zed place multiple malloc calls" - He was testing my faith in humanity

Comment: @EdHeal by that line , do you mean that there is an obvious answer to that , and that my line of thinking is wrong?

Comment: Because he wanted more memory from the stack (that is the purpose of `malloc`)

Comment: Didn't Zed get killed in Pulp fiction?

Comment: Is there a real problem you want help with here?

Comment: @ryyker I am not sure what you mean by that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple malloc calls in `Database_open()` because the `struct Connection` contains a pointer to a `struct Database` instead of incorporating a `struct Database` directly.  That could have been done like so:

```
struct Connection {
    FILE *file;
    struct Database db;     // directly incorporate a `struct Database`
};
```

In effect, that's what you've done in your `struct wtf2` example. There are design decisions that can make it so one method might be better than the other for various reasons. I'm not familiar with the "Learn C the Hard Way" series, so I can't comment on whether or not the design choices were discussed well.

As for using stack based Address objects to initialize the array, that's a convenience of C's object initialization, mentioned in the comment as making a prototype:

```
    // make a prototype to initialize it
    struct Address addr = {.id = i, .set = 0};
```

In C, there's no such thing as a structure literal that could be directly assigned to `conn->db->rows[i]`. But in the declaration of struct object, an initializer can be provided to initialize the object.  So that's what happening here - a declaration of a `struct Address` object is used merely to provide the convenience of being able to specify the initializer,  Then that object is immediately assigned to the heap allocated struct (which is what we really wanted initialized).  The sequence of code is more or less equivalent to:

```
    memset( &conn->db->rows[i], 0, sizeof(conn->db->rows[i]));
    conn->db->rows[i].id = i;
```

Comment: Ah my bad, I overlooked the pointer in the Connection struct.